# How can I implement (and test) in app purchases for a client without their dev certificate?

Tags: iphone, certificate, in-app-purchase, provisioning

I have a client who wants to do in app purchase on some of their apps, but obviously they don't want to have to give me their developer certificate (not even sure if that's possible). Can someone tell me if there is sosmething I'm missing so that I'll be able to fully test out in app purchase for them without having to do everything under my dev cert and then replicate all the itunes connect stuff on their identity?

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this for a client in the past and could find no way around setting up a dummy app under my own dev certificate and adding purchases to that.

You shouldn't need to add many purchases in order to get your code up and working (and testable), and the creation of in app purchases is a very quick process now anyway.

Your code for handling purchases will likely remain the same regardless of which account you create the purchases under. Unless you have access to their account you would have to duplicate all this when it comes time to shipping the app anyway, since the purchases are tied to the app id being submitted.

Comment: yeah it was helpful to to use macros for the product names then we changed them all in one place etc.